# ASP.NET MVC Chart Helper. How to set different color for each Bar/Column on chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I am using the ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Chart Helper.

Fore some reason colors scheme (e.g `Rainfall`) applied only for Pie and Doughnut charts and not for any another types (Bar, Column etc).

The bars/columns on all another charts has all the same color. How to fix that?

Here is my chart:

```
chart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 100, height: 200)
                .AddSeries(
                    chartType: Bar,
                    legend: Rainfall
                    xValue: new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" },
                    yValues: new[] { "20", "20", "40", "10", "10" });
            }
```

Also i was trying to use all schemes from `System.Web.Helpers public static class ChartTheme`, none of these helped

Answer (score 6):

I found something that works ... its not great but it works

using the old Charting

using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

---

```
 public ActionResult GetRainfallChart()
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(1400);
        chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(750);

        Series series1 = new Series("Series1");
        series1.ChartArea = "ca1";
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        series1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 11f, FontStyle.Regular);
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "A",
            YValues = new double[] { 100 },
            Color = Color.Green,
        });
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "B",
            YValues = new double[] { 324 },
            Color = Color.Red,
        });
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "C",
            YValues = new double[] { 235 },
            Color = Color.Yellow,
        });

        chart.Series.Add(series1);

        ChartArea ca1 = new ChartArea("ca1");
        ca1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca1);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");



    }
```

Yes he is correct. One more information
Chart Helper in System.Web.Helpers internally use 'using DV = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;' ASP.Net chart control only but wrapped with limited access.

Its better you can use ASP.Net chart if you need more functions

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you found the answer a long time ago but given the fact that I found very little on this topic when searching for a way to colorize the bars of a chart I thought it might be useful to post the solution here when it opened up to me.

It seems that the implementation of *System.Web.Helpers.Chart* is closely related to *System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart*. Given this, I managed to find some clues as to how I could configure the "theme" XML properties:

```
public const String CHARTS_THEME = @"<Chart BackColor=""#EFEFEF"" BackGradientStyle=""TopBottom"" BorderColor=""#A0A0A0"" BorderWidth=""1"" Palette=""None"" PaletteCustomColors=""#ffcc00"" >
<ChartAreas>
<ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Transparent"" BackSecondaryColor=""White"" BorderWidth=""1"" BorderColor=""#A0A0A0"" BorderDashStyle=""Solid"" >
<AxisY>
<MajorGrid Interval=""Auto"" LineColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"" />    
<LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 10pt"" />
</AxisY>
<AxisX LineColor=""#000000"">
<MajorGrid Interval=""Auto"" LineColor=""64, 64, 64, 64"" />
<LabelStyle Font=""Verdana, 10pt"" />
</AxisX>
</ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
<Legends>
<Legend _Template_=""All"" BackColor=""Transparent"" Docking=""Bottom"" Font=""Verdana, 10pt, style=Plain"" LegendStyle=""Row"">
</Legend>
    </Legends>                          
</Chart>";
```

Key to this point is to define your own ***PaletteCustomColors*** (I have only one color). To make this work, the ***Palette*** property must be set to *None*.

Finally, just use your theme when creating an instance of your chart:

```
Chart chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 200, theme:CHARTS_THEME);
```

Also check out the msdn documentation of *System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart* to discover other ways to style your chart:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467201.aspx